# _loaddqu_LE intrinsic stores in reverse order

Tags: c, x86, byte, bit

`_loaddqu_LE` intrinsic stores in reverse order. Please suggest a workaround or use array to first rearrange bytes before using `_loaddqu_LE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
uint32_t src[16];
__m128i a; /* 128 bit */

src[0] = 0x00000000;
src[1] = 0x00000000;
src[2] = 0x00000000;
src[3] = 0x00000000;
src[4] = 0x63636362;
src[5] = 0x63636362;
src[6] = 0x63636362;
src[7] = 0x63636362;
src[8] = 0xc998989b;
src[9] = 0xaafbfbf9;
src[10] =0xc998989b; 
src[11] =0xaafbfbf9;
src[12] =0x50349790;
src[13] =0xfacf6c69;
src[14] =0x3357f4f2;
src[15] =0x99ac0f0b;

/* load 32 bits */
a = _loaddqu_LE((const char _ptr64 *) & (((__m128i *)src)[0]));
printf("0x%016llx%016llx\n", a.v0, a.v1);
a = _loaddqu_LE((const char _ptr64 *) & (((__m128i *)src)[1]));
printf("0x%016llx%016llx\n", a.v0, a.v1);

return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000
0x62636363626363636263636362636363
```

Expected output:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000
0x63636362636363626363636263636362
```

Comment: Please review your question and with the help here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting improve the readability.

Comment: Also, taking the [tour] is something of a good-luck charm here. People appreciate askers who at least invested that much of an effort.

Comment: Having repeated meaningless sentences in your question gives the impression that you worked around the systems restriction on questions with mostly code and hardly any explanation. That is something to avoid.

Comment: sorry for repeated statement , it was by mistake . can u please help with the code.

Comment: This doesn't compile on my system. What compiler/compiler options are you using?

Comment: If you want bytes in memory order, use a normal intrinsic like `_mm_loadu_si128`.  What the heck does `_loaddqu_LE` do?  Does it actually byte-reverse dword elements with `pshufb`?

Comment: The only google result for `_loaddqu_LE` is a deleted SO question from ~2 weeks ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012493/combine-8-consecutive-bytes-as-a-uint64-t.  It may have something to do with endian-conversion, so don't use it if that's not what you want.  But commenters there had never heard of it either.

Comment: @PeterCordes: DuckDuckGo finds [an hpe.com PDF file](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02128447&docLocale=en_US), which says `_loaddqu_LE()` is the name TNS/X C/C++ uses for [SSE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) LDDQU instruction, and is equivalent to the `_mm_lddqu_si128` intrinsic.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: either their compiler is broken, or that intrinsic isn't supposed to be just `lddqu`.  I guess LDDQU + a pointer-type-dependent byte swap. I changed the OP's source to use `_mm_lddqu_si128( &(((__m128i *)src)[1]));` and printf `a[0], a[1]` (GNU C vector indexing), and I get the expected `0x63636362636363626363636263636362`, same byte order as the source array.  `lddqu` has identical behaviour to `movdqu` on modern x86, and a perf difference on Pentium4.  (It needs a different opcode because it observably touches more bytes if used on an uncacheable MMIO region, that's all.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: If it indeed is Hewlett Packard Enterprise stuff, then it is basically certain that it is broken somehow; all enterprisey types are more interested in customer retention (restriction to their costly products) than something silly like sensible operation. (Apologies for ranting; I've just seen too much horrible "enterprisey" products, and basically none acceptable ones.) I wrote my "answer" in the hopes that OP will understand what the true underlying problem was, and tell us (in a separate answer) how they solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a 128-bit unsigned integer

```
28018020645823955151501786048551321856
```

In hexadecimal, it is

```
0x15141312111009080706050403020100
```

On architectures that use [little-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), like 64-bit Intel/AMD (which is the most likely candidate, considering the `__m128i` type used), that number is stored in memory in hexadecimal as

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x10 0x11 0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15
```

We can reinterpret these bytes for example as eight 16-bit unsigned integers,

```
0x0100 0x0302 0x0504 0x0706 0x0908 0x1110 0x1312 0x1514
```

or four 32-bit unsigned integers,

```
0x03020100 0x07060504 0x11100908 0x15141312
```

or two 64-bit unsigned integers,

```
0x0706050403020100 0x1514131211100908
```

OP wishes to split the 128-bit unsigned integer input into two 64-bit unsigned integers.  The Intel/AMD intrinsics provide the `_mm_shuffle_epi8()` and `_mm_set_epi8()` intrinsics for this. (If OP is using TNS/X C/C++, the equivalent intrinsics are `_pshufb()` and `_mm_set_epi8()`.)

The `_mm_set_epi8()` intrinsic takes 16 parameters, most significant byte first, and packs them into an 128-bit integer. The `_mm_shuffle_epi8()`/`_pshufb()` intrinsics take two 128-bit integers as parameters, and returns an 128-bit integer, constructed from the bytes in the first parameter, as directed by bytes in the second parameter.

---

Here are some useful byte order constants:

```
/* SWAP128_128 = _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15); */
#define  SWAP128_128  { 579005069656919567LL, 283686952306183LL }

/* SWAP128_64 = _mm_set_epi8(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); */
#define  SWAP128_64  { 283686952306183LL, 579005069656919567LL };

/* SWAP128_32 = _mm_set_epi8(12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3); */
#define  SWAP128_32  { 289644378169868803LL, 868365760874482187LL }; 

/* SWAP128_16 = _mm_set_epi8(14, 15, 12, 13, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1); */
#define  SWAP128_16  { 434320308619640833LL, 1013041691324254217LL };

const __m128i  swap128_128 = SWAP128_128;
const __m128i  swap128_64  = SWAP128_64;
const __m128i  swap128_32  = SWAP128_32;
const __m128i  swap128_16  = SWAP128_16;
```

Note that the constant declaration assumes that the C compiler implements the `__m128i` type as if it was two `long long`s (as far as I know, all that support those for SSE3 do). In any case, you can construct the constants using the `_mm_set_epi8()` intrinsic.

The reason for putting them as macros, is that if you encounter a [compiler or architecture](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) that requires different type of declaration to get the same effective value (as the respective `_mm_set_epi8()` intrinsic yields), you only need a small bit of preprocessor massaging.

Using the above, `a = _mm_shuffle_epi8(a, swap128_128);` (or `a = _pshufb(a, swap128_128)` for TNS/X C/C++) reverses the entire byte order; `swap128_64` just the byte order for both 64-bit components, `swap128_32` for all four 32-bit components, and `swap128_16` for all eight 16-bit components.  There are eleven other variations (plus "no shuffle", for a total of 16 byte orders for 128 bit values), plus you can duplicate source bytes to target bytes, so do use the `_mm_set_epi8()` to find the one you need.

Given the above data,

```
const uint8_t  data[16] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15
};
__m128i vector = _mm_lddqu_si128((const __m128i *)data);
__m128i v128 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector, swap128_128);
__m128i v64 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector, swap128_64);
__m128i v32 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector, swap128_32);
__m128i v16 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vector, swap128_16);
```

will yield:

```
vector = 0x0706050403020100 0x1514131211100908
       = 0x03020100 0x07060504 0x11100908 0x15141312
       = 0x0100 0x0302 0x0504 0x0706 0x0908 0x1110 0x1312 0x1514
       = 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x10 0x11 0x12 0x13 0x14 0x15

v128 = 0x0809101112131415 0x0001020304050607
     = 0x12131415 0x08091011 0x04050607 0x00010203
     = 0x1415 0x1213 0x1011 0x0809 0x0607 0x0405 0x0203 0x0001
     = 0x15 0x14 0x13 0x12 0x11 0x10 0x09 0x08 0x07 0x06 0x05 0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01 0x00

v64 = 0x0001020304050607 0x0809101112131415
    = 0x04050607 0x00010203 0x12131415 0x08091011
    = 0x0607 0x0405 0x0203 0x0001 0x1415 0x1213 0x1011 0x0809
    = 0x07 0x06 0x05 0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01 0x00 0x15 0x14 0x13 0x12 0x11 0x10 0x09 0x08

v32 = 0x0405060700010203 0x1213141508091011
    = 0x00010203 0x04050607 0x08091011 0x12131415
    = 0x0203 0x0001 0x0607 0x0405 0x1011 0x0809 0x1415 0x1213
    = 0x03 0x02 0x01 0x00 0x07 0x06 0x05 0x04 0x11 0x10 0x09 0x08 0x15 0x14 0x13 0x12

v16 = 0x0607040502030001 0x1415121310110809
    = 0x02030001 0x06070405 0x10110809 0x14151213
    = 0x0001 0x0203 0x0405 0x0607 0x0809 0x1011 0x1213 0x1415
    = 0x01 0x00 0x03 0x02 0x05 0x04 0x07 0x06 0x09 0x08 0x11 0x10 0x13 0x12 0x15 0x14
```

depending on how you wish to interpret each `__m128i`. (The first one is as two 64-bit integers, second as four 32-bit integers, third as eight 16-bit integers, and fourth as sixteen bytes.)

There are many other possible variations (for 128 bit values, 16 unique byte orders are possible), but without knowing exactly what is the underlying problem and what it is that OP is trying to achieve, I won't bother exploring them all.